# How to check if a requested user has a specific custom permission in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I want to check with a boolean answer of True/False if a requested user has a permission defined in permissions.py.

More in particular, I want to check if the requested user has the permission of **IsDriver**. Is somehow possible?

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsChargingStationOwner |IsDriver | IsReadOnlyStations]
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get the request user
        requested_user = self.request.user
        if requested_user.is_anonymous :
            print('1')
        elif requested_user .... :
            print('2')
```

My question has to do with the elif statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom permission class that inherits

> rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission

check DRF Permission docs
[here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions)

and if you want to recall it again inside any method you can use @gtopal approach:

```
elif IsDriver().has_permission(self.request, self):
     print('2')
```

Comment: I have already defined a permission as you said. My problem was how to call the has_permission function from the defined class.

Comment: @gtopal got it correct, you can try that too